# jQuery next() with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My DOM is like this (somehow):

```
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<div class="preview"></div>
<a href="#">link</a>
```

If I click on the first link, i want to add some info on the line `div`.

I tried to select it and put data in with `$(this).next('.preview').html(data);` but i didn't get any result.

Comment: jQuery `next()` is only getting the *'immediately following sibling'* of the element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/),

```
$(this).nextAll('.preview').first().html(data);
```

or you can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(this).siblings('.preview').first().html(data);
```

---

- `nextAll()` : Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
- `siblings()`: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.